# AddOnScreenDebugMessage not working in altered engine functions ue4

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, viewport, unreal-engine4

Hey I'm playing around with `FMapProperty::ImportText_Internal` function to try and figure out how it works. But the problem is when ever I put `AddOnScreenDebugMessage` in it to see how it executes It doesn't print to screen.

I've tried removing `AddOnScreenDebugMessage` from the if statement, and it doesn't crash so I don't think the problem is that it can't access GEngine.

I've noticed this with other parts of the engine source code as wall when I try to test it, can any one explain why its not working.

Example code

```
const TCHAR* FMapProperty::ImportText_Internal(const TCHAR* Buffer, void* Data, int32 PortFlags, UObject* Parent, FOutputDevice* ErrorText) const
{
    //Not working
    if (GEngine)
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Some debug message!"));

    checkSlow(KeyProp);
    checkSlow(ValueProp);

    FScriptMapHelper MapHelper(this, Data);
    MapHelper.EmptyValues();

    // If we export an empty array we export an empty string, so ensure that if we're passed an empty string
    // we interpret it as an empty array.
    if (*Buffer++ != TCHAR('('))
    {
        return nullptr;
    } 

    SkipWhitespace(Buffer);
    if (*Buffer == TCHAR(')'))
    {
        return Buffer + 1;
    }

    uint8* TempPairStorage   = (uint8*)FMemory::Malloc(MapLayout.ValueOffset + ValueProp->ElementSize);

    bool bSuccess = false;
    ON_SCOPE_EXIT
    {
        FMemory::Free(TempPairStorage);

        // If we are returning because of an error, remove any already-added elements from the map before returning
        // to ensure we're not left with a partial state.
        if (!bSuccess)
        {
            MapHelper.EmptyValues();
        }
    };

    for (;;)
    {
        KeyProp->InitializeValue(TempPairStorage);
        ValueProp->InitializeValue(TempPairStorage + MapLayout.ValueOffset);
        ON_SCOPE_EXIT
        {
            ValueProp->DestroyValue(TempPairStorage + MapLayout.ValueOffset);
            KeyProp->DestroyValue(TempPairStorage);
        };

        if (*Buffer++ != TCHAR('('))
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        // Parse the key
        SkipWhitespace(Buffer);
        Buffer = KeyProp->ImportText(Buffer, TempPairStorage, PortFlags | PPF_Delimited, Parent, ErrorText);
        if (!Buffer)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        // Skip this element if it's already in the map
        bool bSkip = MapHelper.FindMapIndexWithKey(TempPairStorage) != INDEX_NONE;

        SkipWhitespace(Buffer);
        if (*Buffer++ != TCHAR(','))
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        // Parse the value
        SkipWhitespace(Buffer);
        Buffer = ValueProp->ImportText(Buffer, TempPairStorage + MapLayout.ValueOffset, PortFlags | PPF_Delimited, Parent, ErrorText);
        if (!Buffer)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        SkipWhitespace(Buffer);
        if (*Buffer++ != TCHAR(')'))
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        if (!bSkip)
        {
            int32  Index   = MapHelper.AddDefaultValue_Invalid_NeedsRehash();
            uint8* PairPtr = MapHelper.GetPairPtrWithoutCheck(Index);

            // Copy over imported key and value from temporary storage
            KeyProp  ->CopyCompleteValue_InContainer(PairPtr, TempPairStorage);
            ValueProp->CopyCompleteValue_InContainer(PairPtr, TempPairStorage);
        }

        SkipWhitespace(Buffer);
        switch (*Buffer++)
        {
            case TCHAR(')'):
                MapHelper.Rehash();
                bSuccess = true;
                return Buffer;

            case TCHAR(','):
                SkipWhitespace(Buffer);
                break;

            default:
                return nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code to see what's happening?

Comment: Do you mean with break points

Comment: Yes, with an attached debugger and breakpoints.